# How can I remove name not found errors in TypeScript to Apps Script code in VS Code?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, google-apps-script, clasp

I recently transferred my entire code base from the Apps Script Editor to VSCode with Typescript (with clasp). Since I didn't want to just use one large file for everything (especially since some data shouldn't be pushed to GitHub due to security reasons), I instead broke my code into many files, with 1 main file with all the functions and the rest of the files serving as data holders.

The IDE immediately found errors because TypeScript can't find the names (`ts(2304)`) in the main file since these were declared in other files. I tried exporting the variables of the other files for a few hours, but then found out that the project was failing to compile the whole time because Apps Script doesn't support the export/import scheme. It's only a problem within the IDE; when pushing the code base to Apps Script it runs fine without errors (I think because it's putting everything in one huge file then running it as that).

```js
// for example

function calendarReminderSystem() {
    // get calendar
    let calendar: Calendar = CalendarApp.getOwnedCalendarById(CALENDAR_ID)
    console.log(`Calendar: ${calendar.getName()}`)

    // get date
    let now = new Date()
    now.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)
    let end = new Date(now.getTime() + 7 * DAY)
    end.setHours(23, 59, 59, 999)
    console.log(`now: ${now.getTime()}, 7 from now: ${end.getTime()}`)

    // email addresses
    const sharedUsers = cleanEmails(EMAIL_ADDRESSES)
    console.log(`Users: ${sharedUsers}`)

    // ...
}
```

Here, `CALENDAR_ID`, `DAY`, and `EMAIL_ADDRESSES` are all constants included in other files, but since I haven't done any import/export VSC throws red lines at me, but the thing still works when pushed to Apps Script.

*Just to note if needed: I don't have a `tsconfig.json` in my folder, I let Apps Script handle the configurations for me because I am a newbie who is extremely new to TypeScript after being tired of dealing with JavaScript shenanigans.*

Is there a way to remove these red lines without using import/export? Is there also a way for VSC to throw red lines when the variables are indeed nowhere to be found in the whole code base?

Comment: You can also create a empty tsconfig file.